# I am storing the details in my table as well as sending in GA.Why there is huge difference in users in my database and Google analytics?

Tags: php, mysql, google-analytics

Every users who is visiting my web page I store ip address and also send details of the user to the Google analytics (GA). But after 2 days I see my database table is showing 150k users but GA shows 6000 users.

I am using cloud flare variable to store IP address below is the syntax how I am getting the IP

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']
```

How can I prevent this? I am storing only unique IP addresses

Comment: Robots w/o Javascript enabled, spammers who are filtered by bot filtering, users who have opted out from tracking, maybe user who request resources that do not contain tracking code. And storing IP addresses in Google Analytics might violate their TOS w/r/t personally identifiable data.

Comment: Yes, I am not storing ip address in GA but user sessions are showing nearly 6k, **So how can I prevent this BOTs**  and I see in my table there are lot of IPv6 addresses as well.